# Вывод одной строки на каждое имя с учетом метки

Tags: sql

Есть таблица `stuff_id` с полями `id` и `name`.
Есть таблица `stuff_phone` с полями `id`, `phone`, `preference`.

У одного сотрудника может быть несколько телефонов. У одного из его телефонов может быть предпочтение, в таком случае для этого телефона в поле `preference` стоит какая-то метка, скажем, `'p'`.

Нужен запрос, который выводит информацию в виде "имя - номер" для всех сотрудников, причём для каждого сотрудника нужно вывести только один номер, и если у него есть номер с предпочтением, то именно этот, в противном случае любой его.

Как написать такой запрос?

UPD:
Для связи таблиц используется поле `id`. Можно считать поле `preference` битовым - не суть. Хотелось бы какое-то стандартное ANSI решение, которое работало бы везде, а так всё равно на какой реализации. Главное - суть вопроса, а не нюансы. Как сделать такое объединение таблиц, чтобы имени ставился в соответствие один номер из множества?

Comment: сначала в таблицу номеров добавьте `stuff_id` для связи номера с человеком, иначе как вы поймете который  номер к чему относится? поле `preference` является флагом, поэтому сделайте его в соответствии с диалектом БД в битовое или целочисленное поле, чтобы значения были 0 или 1. А потом почитайте про подзапросы.

Comment: и да, укажите разновидность SQL: `mysql`, `sql server`, `oracle`,`ms access` и т.д. в тэгах вопроса

Comment: А заодно уточните, нужно ли выводить запись о сотруднике, если у него нет ни одного телефона.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно подзапросом в поле:

```
SELECT stuff_id.Id, stuff_id.name,
   (select top 1 stuff_phone.phone from stuff_phone where stuffid = stuff_id.Id 
  order by  stuff_phone.preference) phone
FROM stuff_id
```

(для MSSQL работать будет)

Для MySQL и других СУБД, поддерживающих `LIMIT`, вместо `top`:

```
SELECT stuff_id.Id, stuff_id.name,
   (select stuff_phone.phone from stuff_phone where stuffid = stuff_id.Id 
     order by stuff_phone.preference
     limit 1) phone
FROM stuff_id
```

Раз уж затронута тема первая строка из выборки, то приведу как звучит это в разных субд:

- MSSQL,SYBASE,db2: `select top 1 stuff_phone.phone from stuff_phone
  where stuffid = stuff_id.Id`
- informix,firebird `select first 1 stuff_phone.phone from stuff_phone where stuffid=stuff_id.Id`
- oracle <12 `select stuff_phone.phone from stuff_phone where stuffid =
  stuff_id.Id and rownum=1`
- oracle 12 `select stuff_phone.phone from stuff_phone where stuffid =
  stuff_id.Id fetch first 1 rows only`
- MySql `select stuff_phone.phone from stuff_phone where stuffid = stuff_id.Id limit 1`

Comment: Для db2 тоже, спасибо :)

Comment: Я добавил в ваш ответ MySQL вариант, а то там то же самое по MySQL спрашивают, собираюсь сюда ссылку дубля делать

Comment: @Mike видел вопрос, не вчитался. Я за. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

ANSI решение:

```
SELECT st.Id, st.name, coalesce(max(ph1.phone),max(ph2.phone)) as phone
  FROM stuff as st
  LEFT JOIN stuff_phone ph1 ON st.id = ph1.id and ph1.preference='p'
  LEFT JOIN stuff_phone ph2 ON st.id = ph2.id and ph2.preference!='p'
 GROUP BY st.Id, st.name
```

Или:

```
SELECT st.Id, st.name,
       coalesce(max(case when ph1.preference='p' then ph1.phone end),
                max(ph1.phone)) as phone
  FROM stuff as st
  LEFT JOIN stuff_phone ph1 ON st.id = ph1.id
 GROUP BY st.Id, st.name
```

Но конечно, практически в любой современной СУБД найдется более быстрое решение.

Comment: да, тоже работает, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой вариант, но может будет предложен лучше

```
SELECT st.Id, st.name, ph.phone FROM stuff_id as st
INNER JOIN  stuff_phone as ph ON ph.stuffid = st.Id 
WHERE ph.Id = 
(SELECT Top 1 id from stuff_phone 
WHERE st.Id = stuff_phone.stuffId 
Order By stuff_phone.preference)
GROUP BY st.Id, st.name, ph.phone
```

Comment: не слишком ли сложный у вас запрос?  Если делаете подзапрос, то зачем джойн нужен?

Comment: @teran что вы имеете ввиду? убрать join из вложенного запроса?

Comment: посмотрите на соседний вариант ответа с подзапросом и без джойнов. Тут либо чисто подзапрос, либо джойн с группировкой нужны.

Comment: @teran группировку добавил, если конечно, это имелось ввиду.

Comment: Мне кажется, что благодаря `top 1`, выборка вернёт один номер телефона. Сотрудников - возможно несколько, а номер один `ph.ID=`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот запрос по стандарту ANSI, должен работать на любом бренде

```
SELECT s.*, p.phone  
FROM stuff AS s 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, phone, preference, 
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY preference) rnum
    FROM phone_stuff) AS p ON p.id = s.id and p.rnum = 1
```