# Как получить только первые совпадения в JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

Есть таблицы:

*offers*

```
offer_id item_id is_main
1        1       1
2        1       0
3        1       0
4        2       0 
5        2       0
6        3       0
7        3       1
```

*divisions*

```
item_id     division_id
1           1
2           1
3           1
```

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT offers.offer_id , offers.item_id FROM offers
JOIN divisions ON offers.item_id = divisions.item_id
WHERE divisions.division_id IN (1)
```

Результат должен быть таким: `offer_id (1, 4, 7)`, т.е. должен возвращаться только один `offer_id` от каждого `item_id`. Если существует `offer_id` с `is_main = 1`, то - он, если нет - то первый сортировкой по `offer_id`.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615714/sql-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F/615766#615766

Comment: в mysql select top 1 не работает

Comment: А вы мой вариант от туда возьмите. он везде работает. а так то top в mysql надо заменить на `limit 1` в конце запроса

Comment: не пойдет. Но уже разобрался: SELECT * FROM offers WHERE item_id IN (SELECT divisions.item_id FROM divisions WHERE divisions.division_id IN (1)) GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY offers.is_main

Comment: @lecherg и вас не беспокоит, что этот запрос, во-первых, выдаёт некорректный результат, а во-вторых, в `SELECT` присутствуют столбцы, которые и не в агрегирующей функции, и не в `GROUP BY`?

Comment: еще как подойдет, надо только правильно применить. А ваш вариант если сработал на ваших данных - то вам повезло, без групповых функций возвращается первое попавшееся значение, если те же самые записи вставлять в таблицу  в другом порядке - то результат может отличаться, т.к. он зависит от физического положения записей на диске

Comment: @Mike ваш вариант (второй из ответа) в MySQL 5.7, кстати, не работает, ибо в нём `WHERE`, а должен быть `ON`. В связи с чем вопрос: вы не против, если я размещу ответ на базе вашего решения с переименованиями?

Comment: разве `coalesce(min(case when is_main=1 then offer_id),min(offer_id))` не работает ? при вашем group by конечно

Comment: @Regent А смысл, я тот поправил, там ON более уместен, конечно. А этот мне кажется по дублю надо будет закрыть, после того как у автора окончательно получится

Comment: @Mike если исправили, то можно и закрывать как дубликат. Кстати, как вы сами заметили в комментарии, для второго `MAX` (или `MIN` в данном вопросе) можно просто указать само поле, что уменьшает длину запроса на добрых пару десятков символов). Возможно, стоит и в ответе это сделать.

Comment: Ну и если всё же есть какие-то сложности с тем, чтобы взять и переименовать поля: `SELECT d.item_id, COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN is_main = 1 THEN offer_id END), MIN(offer_id)) AS offer_id FROM divisions AS d LEFT JOIN offers AS o ON o.item_id = d.item_id GROUP BY d.item_id`.

Comment: @Regent Я там и в вариант с top дописал версию с limit